# Form validates HTML controls but doesn't submit in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have developed a website in CodeIgniter 4 framework. One particular page has a form that doesn't submit but validates HTML input controls that have required attributes. I have tried everything but could not find the exact bug. Following is the live URL of that page:
https://spcollegedumka.ac.in/index.php/feedback/send

```
<form method="post" id="feedbackForm">
                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <label class="form-label">Who you are?</label>
                            <select name="category" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="">
                                <option value="" selected="" disabled="">---- Select ----</option>
                                <option value="Student">Student</option>
                                <option value="Parent">Parent</option>
                                <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <label class="form-label">Your Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <label class="form-label">Roll No. (students only)</label>
                            <input type="text" name="roll" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-2">
                            <label class="form-label">Select Faculty</label>
                            <select name="faculty" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="">
                                <option value="" selected="" disabled="">---- Select ----</option>
                                                                                                    <option value="1">Faculty of Humanities</option>
                                                                    <option value="2">Faculty of Social Science</option>
                                                                    <option value="3">Faculty of Commerce</option>
                                                                    <option value="4">Faculty of Science</option>
                                                                <option value="100">Not Applicable (For Parent/Guest)</option>
                                                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="mb-2">
                                    <label class="form-label">Mobile No.</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="mb-4">
                                    <label class="form-label">Email Address</label>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-sm">SUBMIT & GO NEXT</button>                       
                    </form>
```

Comment: Could you also show the CodeIgniter controller method that handles the submitted form?

Comment: `public function send(){    
  $data['nav'] = 7;
  $data['title'] = 'Send Feedback';
  return view('feedback_send', $data);
 }`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you! I have found that the issue was coming from the hosting space configurations. Now, It is working just fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know wht u mean, but try to read attribut required

```
required="true"
or 
required
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: Tried that too!

Comment: Sorry for bothering you! I have found that the issue was coming from the hosting space configurations. Now, It is working just fine. Thanks again.